# jQuery slide between two divs with image toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a jQuery animation that I need some help with.

The goal is to slide down to a subsequent div when a user clicks on an image (arrow-down.png). When this image is clicked and the page scrolls to the next div, the image src changes (to arrow-up.png) and allows the user to slide back up to the original div where again the image is set to its original state.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="ninth panel">
 <div class="separator">
<img class="img-swap" src="images/arrow-down.png">
 </div>
 <div class="contact-form">
 <!-- code for form here -->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Trying to make sense of what you want to do and it's not clear. Is this sort of what you're starting with: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/RTFk4/

Comment: Not what I had in mind exactly but thank you for trying to help, I've found a solution that achieves my desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it for a little while I've managed to get the effect that I was looking for. This code could most likely be optimised as I am no expert but it might help somebody down the line.

```
$("span.img-swap.down").on("click", function() {
    // Checks if class is set to down, initiates animation, stop animation, then toggles classess
    if ($('span.img-swap').is('.down')) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('div.ninth.panel').offset().top }, 2000 );
        $('span.img-swap').toggleClass('down up');
    } 
    // If class is not down, checks if class is set to up, initiates animation, stop animation, then toggles classess
    else if ($('span.img-swap').is('.up')) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('div.eighth.panel').offset().top }, 2000 );
        $('span.img-swap').toggleClass('up down');
    }
});
```